# excel spreadsheet sum by group

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to determine winning percentage.

problem is, 1 transaction may have any number of buys or sells til next transaction(sell).

example.

not sure to use sumifs, or group, i'm lost,

thanks for any help

[image: data example]

Comment: It's exciting issue to attempt, is like getting running balance.

Answer (score 2):

Put this in C2 and copy down:

```
=IF(AND(OR(A3="SELL",A3=""),A2="BUY"),SUM($B$2:B2)-SUM($C$1:C1),"")
```

It simply sums up column B to that point and subtracts the amounts already accounted for.

[image]

Comment: works perfectly, sorry for the delay, had to translate it into spanish, so grateful Scott

Comment: Please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: @ScottCraner,, nicely solved is tricky one but working.